# RACKET menu choice

Tags: variables, input, racket

I am trying to establish a menu so the program can change based on user input.  This seems to work but I wanted to see if it was the "RIGHT" way of doing it.  Also when the program runs after I input a number I get a (void) displayed.  How can I make the (void) go away.  Any help would be appreciated....thank you.

```
(printf "Choose your difficulty\n")
(printf "1. Easy\n")
(printf "2. Medium\n")
(printf "3. Hard\n")
(printf "4. Insane\n")

(define choice (read))
(define (choose c)
  (cond [(= c 1)(set! amount 3)]
        [(= c 2)(set! amount 7)]
        [(= c 3)(set! amount 10)]
        [(= c 4)(set! amount 99)]
        [else (printf "Invalid choice.\n")]))

(choose choice)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should avoid using `set!`. The functional way to implement this might look like this:

```
(define (choose c)
  (cond [(= c 1) 3]
        [(= c 2) 7]
        [(= c 3) 10]
        [(= c 4) 99]
        [else (printf "Invalid choice.\n") (choose (read))]))

(define amount (choose (read)))
```

Due to the `(choose (read))` inside the `else` clause, the program will ask until it gets a valid input, which is usually what you want. If it isn't, you'll want to figure out a reasonable value for `amount` to have (e.g. a suitable default).

Comment: thank you for this response.  I tried it in my version of Dr. Racket (Advanced Student) and I get the following error for the else statement: cond: expected a clause with a question and an answer, but found a clause with 3 parts.  I have noticed that I can only have one statement after the condition part for each condition.  Am I doing something wrong????  Please advise.